# Writing custom build tasks to generate build dependencies automatically on each build

Tags: gradle, makefile

I'm trying to figure out how to use Gradle. I'm having this problem, which is trivial to solve in Makefiles, CMake, etc, but I have not idea how to do it in Gradle.

Let's say I have an application that contains some resource files inside. Those resource files are generated from a set of input files, and are put inside the application in compiled form.

I'd like to instruct Gradle to automatically generate those resources when it's needed by pointing it to the resource input files. So, effectively I'd like to do something like this:

```
all: out1 out2
    @echo done

out1: in1
    cat in1 | xxd > out1

out2: temp1
    cat temp1 | xxd > out2

temp1: in1
    cat in2 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' > temp1
```

(let's skip this unfortunate effect when if `xxd` will fail then an invalid `out1` will be generated)

Let's say `out1` and `out2` are my resource files that I'd like to embed inside the application. These files are generated by different rules:

- `out1` is generated from `in1` by processing it with `xxd` (it's just an example),
- `out2` is generated from `in2` by first uppercasing it, and then piping it through `xxd`. A temporary file, `temp1` is being created in the meantime, but that's just a temporary file and it's not important at all.

So what I'd like to achieve in Gradle is basically an equivalent of the Makefile script pasted above with all its features; I mostly mean that `out1` and `out2` shouldn't be generated if `in1` and `in2` didn't change (because the resource generation phase can be expensive and time consuming, so I'd like to avoid having to run it on each build), and the possibility of the build system to automatically figure out how to run the build in parallel, so that `out1` and `out2` is being generated at the same time.

I'm trying to dig up the docs for Gradle and some examples, but 95% of what I find are some opaque scripts that use some particular plugin, which nobody explains how it works inside. The docs say that Gradle is an "automation tool", so it should be perfectly doable what I'm trying to achieve, but is it really the case? Is there any sense in trying to use Gradle as a tool for the use-case described in this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal example code generation Gradle task is being presented here:

https://github.com/gradle/native-samples/blob/master/cpp/source-generation/build.gradle

````
plugins {
    id 'cpp-application'
    id 'xcode'
    id 'visual-studio'
}

def codeGeneration = tasks.register("codeGeneration", CodeGenerator) {
    cppDir = project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated/cpp")
    headersDir = project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated/headers")
}

application {
    source.from codeGeneration.flatMap { it.cppDir }
    privateHeaders.from codeGeneration.flatMap { it.headersDir }
}


// Code generation implementation could be in another plugin or buildSrc
class CodeGenerator extends DefaultTask {
    @OutputDirectory
    DirectoryProperty cppDir = project.objects.directoryProperty()
    
    @OutputDirectory
    DirectoryProperty headersDir = project.objects.directoryProperty()

    @TaskAction
    public void generate() {
        generateSources(cppDir.getAsFile().get())
        generateHeaders(headersDir.getAsFile().get())
    }

    private void generateSources(File generatedDir) {
        new File(generatedDir, "main.cpp").text = """
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << MESSAGE << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
        """
    }
    private void generateHeaders(File generatedDir) {
        new File(generatedDir, "header.h").text = """
#pragma once

#define MESSAGE "Hello, World!"
        """
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Doable. Just need a bit of imagination. Gradle tasks can be created at runtime and to my knowledge it needs the inputs you need to generate tasks be ready when you invoke gradle (not sure if tasks can still be created once one task had already started, I haven't personally tried).

For your use case, you may just need to execute a separate gradle command (separate build file) once the input is ready. Gradle allows you to invoke any shell command, so just spawn off another gradle call.

Here's a sample on how you may create new tasks dynamically (multiple tasks are spawned off from an array, you may just read yours from a file): https://github.com/HCL-TECH-SOFTWARE/DX-Modules-and-ScriptApps/blob/main/06ThemeComponentInApp/DxModule/build.gradle